# Issue with HTML2Canvas and jsPDF causing browser freeze in RadiobuttonWithForm case

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm facing browser freezing issues when attempting to convert images into a PDF document using HTML2Canvas and jsPDF specifically within the RadiobuttonWithForm scenario. My current code creates multiple instances of HTML2Canvas for each image conversion, resulting in a freeze of the browser's main thread and potential errors.

I've tried to improve performance and resolve the issue by using Promise.all to perform image conversion asynchronously and in parallel. However, I'm still encountering freezing problems

`           downloadAlt: function(json) {
// Import jsPDF library from the window object
const {
jsPDF
} = window.jspdf;

```
                // Create a jsPDF object with page orientation "portrait", measurement unit "mm", and page format "a4"
                var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

                // Set the page dimensions
                var pageWidth = doc.internal.pageSize.width;
                var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;

                // Set the margins
                var leftMargin = 10;
                var rightMargin = pageWidth - 10;
                var margin = 10;

                // Current position on the page
                var currentY = margin;

                // Add the section titled "Procedure"
                doc.setFont("Verdana", "bold");
                doc.setFontSize(9);
                doc.text("Procedure", leftMargin, currentY);

                // Add a separating line below the word "Procedure"
                doc.setLineWidth(0);
                var addmorespace = 1;
                var marginFactor = 2;
                var space = 5;
                var adjustspace = 10;

                var distancefromtheline = 9;
                doc.line(
                    leftMargin,
                    currentY + addmorespace,
                    rightMargin,
                    currentY + addmorespace,
                    "S"
                );
                currentY += distancefromtheline; // Distance from the line
                var currentX = leftMargin; // Variable to keep track of the horizontal position

                // Select all elements with the attribute "data-printpdf"
                var elementsToPrint = document.querySelectorAll("[data-printpdf]");

                // Iterate through the elements and add the information to the PDF document
                for (var i = 0; i < elementsToPrint.length; i++) {
                    //fare un foreach
                    // This line retrieves the value of the "data-type" attribute associated with the current element.
                    var element = elementsToPrint[i];

                    // Retrieves the value of the "data-type" attribute from the current element
                    // and assigns it to the variable 'elementType'.
                    var elementType = element.getAttribute("data-type");

                    // Use a switch statement to handle different types of elements
                    switch (elementType) {
                        case "FirstTitle":
                            // Set font style and size for h2
                            doc.setFont("Verdana", "bold");
                            doc.setFontSize(13);
                            //is then used to calculate the maximum text parts size

                            // Split the text into parts that fit the page width
                            var textPartsH2 = doc.splitTextToSize(
                                element.textContent,
                                pageWidth - marginFactor * margin
                            );

                            textPartsH2.forEach((part, index) => {
                                // Check if the new current position exceeds the maximum height
                                if (currentY + space > pageHeight - margin) {
                                    // Add a new page if the content exceeds the page height
                                    doc.addPage();
                                    currentY = margin; // Reset the vertical position on the new page
                                }

                                // Add the text to the PDF document
                                doc.text(part, leftMargin, currentY);
                                currentY += adjustspace; // You can adjust the line spacing here
                            });
                            break;

                        case "Text":
                            // Set font size and style for label
                            doc.setFontSize(10);
                            doc.setFont("Verdana", "normal");

                            // Split the text or value into parts that fit the page width
                            var textOrValuePartsLeft = doc.splitTextToSize(
                                element.textContent,
                                pageWidth - marginFactor * margin
                            );

                            textOrValuePartsLeft.forEach((part, index) => {
                                // Check if the new current position exceeds the maximum height
                                if (currentY + adjustspace > pageHeight - margin) {
                                    // Add a new page if the content exceeds the page height
                                    doc.addPage();
                                    currentY = margin; // Reset the vertical position on the new page
                                }

                                // Add the text or value to the PDF document
                                doc.text(part, leftMargin, currentY);
                                currentY += adjustspace; // You can adjust the distance between lines here
                            });
                            break;

                        case "SecondTitle":
                            // Set font size and style for the second title
                            doc.setFontSize(11);
                            doc.setFont("Verdana", "bold");

                            // Split the text or value into parts that fit the page width
                            var textOrValuePartsLeft = doc.splitTextToSize(
                                element.textContent,
                                pageWidth - marginFactor * margin
                            );

                            textOrValuePartsLeft.forEach((part, index) => {
                                // Check if the new current position exceeds the maximum height
                                if (currentY + adjustspace > pageHeight - margin) {
                                    // Add a new page if the content exceeds the page height
                                    doc.addPage();
                                    currentY = margin; // Reset the vertical position on the new page
                                }

                                // Add the text or value to the PDF document
                                doc.text(part, leftMargin, currentY);
                                currentY += adjustspace; // You can adjust the distance between lines here
                            });
                            break;

                        case "Title":
                            // Set font size and style for the title
                            doc.setFontSize(12);
                            doc.setFont("Verdana", "normal");

                            // Check if an inner element with a specific class exists within the element
                            if (
                                (innerElement = element.querySelector(
                                    ".espd-marginLeft1em.ng-binding"
                                ))
                            ) {
                                if (innerElement) {
                                    // Get the trimmed text inside the div
                                    var textInsideDiv = innerElement.innerText.trim();

                                    // Check if there is text content
                                    if (textInsideDiv.length > 0) {
                                        // Split the text into parts that fit the page width
                                        var textPartsDiv = doc.splitTextToSize(
                                            textInsideDiv,
                                            pageWidth - marginFactor * margin
                                        );

                                        textPartsDiv.forEach((part, index) => {
                                            // Check if the new current position exceeds the maximum height
                                            if (currentY + adjustspace > pageHeight - margin) {
                                                // Add a new page if the content exceeds the page height
                                                doc.addPage();
                                                currentY = margin; // Reset the vertical position on the new page
                                            }

                                            // Calculate the height of the rectangle based on the number of lines of the divided text
                                            var lines = doc.splitTextToSize(
                                                part,
                                                pageWidth - marginFactor * margin
                                            );
                                            var lineHeight = 10; // Height of a single line
                                            var rectangleHeight = lines.length * lineHeight; // Total height of the rectangle

                                            // Set fill color and draw a rectangle
                                            doc.setFillColor(238, 226, 238);
                                            doc.rect(
                                                leftMargin,
                                                currentY,
                                                pageWidth - marginFactor * margin,
                                                rectangleHeight,
                                                "F"
                                            );

                                            // Position the text in the center of the rectangle's height
                                            doc.text(
                                                part,
                                                leftMargin,
                                                currentY + lineHeight / marginFactor
                                            );
                                            currentY += rectangleHeight + adjustspace; // Update the vertical position
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case "LabelRoleName":
                            // Set font style and size for the label
                            doc.setFont("Verdana", "bold");
                            doc.setFontSize(10);

                            // Split the text or value into parts that fit the page width
                            var textOrValuePartsLeft = doc.splitTextToSize(
                                element.textContent,
                                pageWidth / marginFactor - margin
                            );

                            textOrValuePartsLeft.forEach((part, index) => {
                                // Check if the new current position exceeds the maximum height
                                if (currentY + adjustspace > pageHeight - margin) {
                                    // Add a new page if the content exceeds the page height
                                    doc.addPage();
                                    currentY = margin; // Reset the vertical position on the new page
                                }

                                const xOffset = 40; // Stores the horizontal offset value used for adjusting the x-coordinate in the document

                                // Use the variable in the code
                                doc.text(part, leftMargin - xOffset, currentY);

                                // Add the text or value to the PDF document
                                doc.text(part, leftMargin - xOffset, currentY);

                                // Update the current position on the page
                                currentY += space;
                            });
                            break;

                        case "LabelProcedure":
                            // Set font style and size for the label
                            doc.setFont("Verdana", "bold");
                            doc.setFontSize(10);

                            // Split the text or value into parts that fit half the page width
                            var textOrValuePartsLeft = doc.splitTextToSize(
                                element.textContent,
                                pageWidth / marginFactor - margin
                            );

                            textOrValuePartsLeft.forEach((part, index) => {
                                // Check if the new current position exceeds the maximum height
                                if (currentY + 10 > pageHeight - margin) {
                                    // Add a new page if the content exceeds the page height
                                    doc.addPage();
                                    currentY = margin; // Reset the vertical position on the new page
                                }

                                // Add the text or value to the PDF document
                                doc.text(part, leftMargin - 37, currentY);

                                // Update the current position on the page
                                currentY += adjustspace; // You can adjust the distance between lines
                            });
                            break;

                        case "Label":
                            // Set font style and size for the label
                            doc.setFont("Verdana", "bold");
                            doc.setFontSize(10);

                            // Split the text or value into parts that fit half the page width
                            var textOrValuePartsLeft = doc.splitTextToSize(
                                element.textContent,
                                pageWidth / marginFactor - margin
                            );

                            textOrValuePartsLeft.forEach((part, index) => {
                                // Check if the new current position exceeds the maximum height
                                if (currentY + adjustspace > pageHeight - margin) {
                                    // Add a new page if the content exceeds the page height
                                    doc.addPage();
                                    currentY = margin; // Reset the vertical position on the new page
                                }

                                // Add the text or value to the PDF document
                                doc.text(part, leftMargin, currentY);

                                // Update the current position on the page
                                currentY += adjustspace; // You can adjust the distance between lines
                            });
                            break;

                        case "Input":
                            // Set font and font size
                            doc.setFont("Verdana", "normal");
                            doc.setFontSize(10);

                            // Get the text or value of the field
                            var textContent =
                                elementType === "Input" &&
                                element &&
                                typeof element.value === "string" ?
                                element.value :
                                "";

                            var textContentParts = [];

                            // Split the text into parts adapted to the page width
                            var words = textContent.split(" ");
                            var currentLine = "";

                            // Iterate through the words in the text
                            for (var word of words) {
                                // Add the current word to the text line being built
                                var testLine = currentLine + word + " ";

                                // Calculate the width of the text line in points
                                var testWidth = doc.getStringUnitWidth(testLine) * adjustspace;

                                // Check if the text line width exceeds the page width, considering margins
                                if (testWidth > pageWidth - marginFactor * margin) {
                                    // Add the current (complete) text line to the array of text parts
                                    textContentParts.push(currentLine.trim());

                                    // Start a new line with the current word
                                    currentLine = word + " ";
                                } else {
                                    // If the text line width doesn't exceed the limit, continue composing the line
                                    currentLine = testLine;
                                }
                            }

                            // Add the last text part (after removing white spaces) to the array of text parts
                            textContentParts.push(currentLine.trim());

                            // Calculate the number of lines based on text content parts
                            var numberOfLines = textContentParts.length;

                            // Check if the current position (currentY) plus the number of text lines exceeds the maximum page height minus the bottom margin
                            if(currentY + numberOfLines > pageHeight - margin) {

                                // If true, add a new page to the document
                                doc.addPage();

                                // Set the new Y position to the top margin of the new page
                                // This ensures that the next text starts from the top margin of the newly added page
                                currentY = margin;
                            }

                            // Calculate rectangle X and Y positions
                            let rectangleOffsetX = 80;
                            let rectangleOffsetY = 15;

                            let rectangleX = rightMargin - rectangleOffsetX;
                            let rectangleY = currentY - rectangleOffsetY;

                            // Calculate text X and Y positions
                            let textXCoordinate = rectangleX;
                            // Define constants for calculations
                            const additionalLines = 5;
                            const divisionFactor = 4;

                            // Calculate text Y coordinate
                            let textYCoordinate =  rectangleY+(numberOfLines + additionalLines) / divisionFactor;

                            // Draw the gray rectangle
                            doc.setFillColor(238, 238, 238);
                            doc.rect(
                                rectangleX,
                                rectangleY,
                                80,
                                numberOfLines * additionalLines + numberOfLines,
                                "F"
                            );

                            // Draw text only if there is content
                            if (textContent.trim() !== "") {
                                doc.setFont("Verdana", "normal");
                                doc.text(
                                    textContentParts.join("\n"),
                                    textXCoordinate,
                                    textYCoordinate, {
                                        align: "left",
                                        baseline: "top",
                                    }
                                );
                                doc.setFont("Verdana", "bold");
                            }
                            break;

                        case "RadiobuttonWithForm":

                        const divelement = element.getElementsByTagName("div");
                        let imagesProcessed = 0;
                        const promises = [];
                    
                        for (const divElement of divelement) {
                            const div = divElement.querySelector(".col-lg-12.espd-divVanilla");
                    
                            if (div) {
                                const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
                                    html2canvas(div).then((canvas) => {
                                        const imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                                        doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 100, 100);
                                        imagesProcessed++;
                                        resolve();
                                    });
                                });
                    
                                promises.push(promise);
                            }
                        }
                    
                        Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                            doc.save("informazioni.pdf");
                        });
                    
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                doc.save("informazioni.pdf");
            }`
```

**What I tried:** I attempted to convert multiple images into a PDF document using HTML2Canvas and jsPDF within the RadiobuttonWithForm scenario. To achieve this, I iterated through div elements, used HTML2Canvas to capture the images, and then added them to the PDF using jsPDF.

**Expected outcome:** I expected the images to be converted asynchronously and added to the PDF in parallel without freezing the browser. My aim was to optimize performance by using Promise.all to handle the asynchronous image conversion processes concurrently.

**Actual outcome:** However, despite implementing Promise.all for asynchronous handling and attempted parallel processing, the browser still freezes during the conversion process. It seems that the excessive instances of HTML2Canvas for image conversion are causing the freeze, and the PDF generation doesn’t complete smoothly.

I'm seeking guidance on how to optimize this asynchronous process effectively to prevent the browser from freezing during PDF creation in the RadiobuttonWithForm case. Any insights or alternative approaches to handle the image conversion and PDF generation asynchronously would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, html2canvas is blocking the main thread. I am also facing the same issue right now. I tried using a web worker but, we can't access the dom elements inside the web worker.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but you use `Promise.all().then(...)`
So, it takes all your files, but after that wait for all promises resolving inside switch